# Why passwd prohibits me from setting "simple" password?

Tags: password, useradd, passwd

I used console command passwd to change my own password that I set straight after the OS installation with useradd command. My original password contained only line characters, without capitalization, numbers or special characters, but passwd prohibits me to set similar (only line characters) password. Why useradd was less strict than passwd? Is there any way to set "simple" password for already existing user?

P.S. I understand that such requirements are often suggested for security reasons, but this my own laptop and my own system.

Comment: what system is this? undoing security settings will require knowing that

Comment: @thrig, GNU/Linux Slackware 14.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password subsystem is configured to enforce a "non-weak" password policy of some sort.

The root user - which is the user you were operating as when you created the account and set the initial password - isn't limited by this policy.

Assuming your user is set up and authorized to use the `sudo` command, you can set your password to be a weak one via

```
sudo passwd yourusername
```

If you set the root user's password and know it, you could also do

```
su -c "passwd yourusername"
```

And enter the root password when prompted.